# Java If vs try-catch overhead

Tags: java, performance, try-catch

I have many packets coming and some of the packets are faulty.

For example, take the following simple implementations of a method for packets:

```
public String tryTrim(packet)
{
    try
    {
       process(packet);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }

    return null;
}
```

Some packet will be faulty and throw an error and it occurs not so frequently but regularly that you cannot avoid.

I have two methods,

one will validate every packet and process it in try block and the

other will catch the faulty packet and make it a valid packet and send it again to the function.

Which one will take less performance overhead.

Comment: What happened when you profiled each approach?

Comment: I am new to java programming.I don't know how to profile.I have not profiled both yet but performance seemed to decrease in both.I am also open to any alternative thoughts!
If I remove try catch block,will it improve performance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a profiling question not useful to anyone else.

Comment: The simplest way to profile is to repeat one of your approaches a bunch of times (say, more than 10,000) and see how long the whole thing takes. Then repeat the process with the other approach. Which one takes longer?

Comment: @KevinWorkman : Thank you kevin.I will try to profile using that.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I'd describe that as benchmarking. Profiling (IMO) includes tracing and relative times in methods. You could try [VisualVM](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/).

Comment: Actually, let's not encourage half-baked profiling. Profiling can be tricky in Java. My advice to the OP is to optimize for readability for now, and only for performance if you see that it's too slow.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Fair enough. Either way, OP needs to do some of it.

Comment: try/catch has very little "overhead".  There is generally no executable code added along the main path, and the only impact on performance is that certain optimizations must be "killed" at the boundaries of the try, catch, and finally clauses.

Comment: @yshavit I actually agree with you. Just trying to answer the actual question at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> one will validate every packet and process it in try block

Unless the validation is pretty trivial, this is already enough to dominate the cost of the try-catch. Don't optimize what doesn't matter. So we could (and should) stop here.

> the other will catch the faulty packet and make it a valid packet and send it again to the function.

You failed to write how this "making valid" works and how much time it may take. Note also that the outcome is very different from the first case, as you process a broken packet after having fixed it, rather than dropping it.

The best advice is that [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

You normally really shouldn't care about such low level stuff (choosing proper algorithms and structures is a different story). Being curious is fine, but then make sure you measure first (using either [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh) or [caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper)).

Using a [profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713940/eclipse-java-profiler) is often more appropriate than benchmarking, but it seems to be even more tricky.